# Non-Sequential Indices Model Binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Data I am trying to bind a list of non sequential items.

My View

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Data.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
            @for (int j = 0; j < Model.Data[i].Count; j++)
             {
              <td class="col-md-2">
              <input type="hidden" name="Data.Index" value="i.ToString()+j.ToString()" />

             @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Data[i][j].HEAD_COUNT_WRKLD)
             @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Data[i][j].WORKLOAD_DETAIL_ID)
             @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Data[i][j].MONTH)
             @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Data[i][j].WORKLOAD_ID)

                                </td>
                            }
                        </tr>
                    }
```

Given post back values:

```
Data[0][0].HEAD_COUNT_WRKLD:5
Data[0][0].WORKLOAD_DETAIL_ID:37
Data[0][0].MONTH:1
Data[0][0].WORKLOAD_ID:29
Data[0][8].HEAD_COUNT_WRKLD:48
Data[0][8].WORKLOAD_DETAIL_ID:
Data[0][8].MONTH:9
Data[0][8].WORKLOAD_ID:29
Data[2][1].HEAD_COUNT_WRKLD:7
Data[2][1].WORKLOAD_DETAIL_ID:2
Data[2][1].MONTH:2
Data[2][1].WORKLOAD_ID:1
Data[2][3].HEAD_COUNT_WRKLD:67
Data[2][3].WORKLOAD_DETAIL_ID:4
Data[2][3].MONTH:4
Data[2][3].WORKLOAD_ID:1
```

And a controller method:

```
public ActionResult SaveChangeChiefDetails(List<List<ETSDetailDto>> Data)
{}
```

Binding doesn't seems to work for me, the parameter always contains missings data. Am I missing something?

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5.

Comment: By default, indexers must start at zero and be consecutive. You cannot bind non-sequential indexers unless a value for the indexer is also posted. Refer [Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)

Comment: but my model is two dimensional array,how can i use an indexer?i need an example.

Comment: Why is it a 2-D array? What is the point?

Comment: i tried this but didnt work.<input type="hidden" name="Data.Index" value="i.ToString()+j.ToString()" >

Comment: It would just need to be `name="Index"` but that's not going to work with  your 2-D array. How are you actually actually generating this data (show your view)?

Comment: ok,i updated my question.with my view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109740/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-tobias).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, the `DefaultModelBinder` will only bind collections where the indexer is zero-based and consecutive unless you also submit a value for the indexer.

In your case your posting non-consecutive indexers so you need 2 inputs to define the indexers, one for the outer collection and one for the inner (nested) collection.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Data.Count; i++)
{
    // outer collection indexer
    <input type="hidden" name="Data.Index" value="@i" />
    @for (int j = 0; j < Model.Data[i].Count; j++)
    {
        // inner collection indexer
        <input type="hidden" name="Data[@i].Index" value="@j" />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Data[i][j].HEAD_COUNT_WRKLD)
        ....
    }
}
```